# count objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, zepto

I have a little js problem and thought this wonderfull community would be able to help me!

Let's say I want to find all `$('footer')` elements and I want to know if there is either 1 or 2 footers on the page.
How would I do that?

using length() or something similar?

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: this is easy to find out just using google

Comment: -1 "This question does not show any research effort"

Comment: I researched. I found lenght() but somehow the way I used it was not compatible with zepto.js (I use that) or I made a mistake. So that's why I asked the question here, to get the correct syntax :)

Comment: @Pablo Fernandez: Almost every question asked here can be found by googling. If every body went that way, we would not need this site, would we?

Comment: @Jawad, read this post: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/ Where Jeff says __"yes, some questions are too simple to be answered"__

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`length`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/length/) property.

```
$('footer').length;
```

Please see [the jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/).

They're really very good, and typing `length` into the search field would dynamically bring the solution to you.

Answer (score 0):

Or use the .size() function - see [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/size/)

```
$('footer').size();
```

Comment: that is actually nice too since it is compatible with zepto.js, the library I use. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can of course just use:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('footer').length;
```

But *footer* is an HTML5 element, many browsers in use do not support it yet.